# Where can I find a big chess database?

Tags: database

I am searching for a big chess games database, in PGN or CBH or SCID format.
ICOfY Base is no longer available, I think. I found nothing in torrent sites (I am searching for something that is legal).

Comment: I found the million games database from the site of rebel by Mr Schröder but is there another one?

Comment: That's also the biggest I found, when I was looking for a free downloadable database recently.

Comment: For what purpose? There are still a couple of general-purpose ones of considerable size out there, but we might help you better if you could narrow it down a bit.

Comment: @chaosflaws : ok, is's because I like to read my chess books having near me my smartphone, and I use it with chessbase for android and I follow the games both with my book and my phone; but on chessbase there are not all games, and I would like to create my own pgn (or scid file) which could replace/complete chessbase.

Answer (score 3):

I use the games published by [The Week In Chess](http://theweekinchess.com/twic), which are published in a weekly basis. These games make a superb database, although maybe you'll miss some historical games. It takes some effort to build the database with all games published to the date, but from then on it's easy to keep it up to date.

It is also possible to download the [Million Database](http://www.top-5000.nl/pgn.htm) and then to keep it up to date with TWIC games.

Answer (score 1):

I know of at least two sources you could use (one is free, the other costs).

1. lichess added a "opening tree" with many games categorized by the moves you play (you get a list and games that share the same move list). I am not sure if you can get the info easily out of this tool, though.
2. chessclub.com or "ICC" offers their database on their website for download for money. Not sure how costly it is, though.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no such database with several millions games in PGN file public on the Internet (and free). You can download it from some sources such as [this](http://katalogbazszachowych.pl/gigabaza.php) and combine them, or use online database such as [chesspack.com](http://chesspack.com)

Answer (score -1):

Possibly [chess.com](http://chess.com). There are millions of games played there, and each one is available for PGN download - for free.